# Can't send image in email with Spring javamail

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-mail

Using spring 4.0.8

Here is my code

```
@Value("classpath:logo.png")
private Resource logoImage;
```

...

```
final MimeMessagePreparator preparator = new MimeMessagePreparator() {
            public void prepare(MimeMessage mimeMessage) throws Exception {
                final MimeMessageHelper message = new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage, true,"UTF-8");
                message.setTo(toEmail);
                message.setSubject("subject");
                message.setFrom(from);
                message.setReplyTo(replyTo);
                message.addInline("logo.png", logoImage);
                message.setText("<img src=\"cid:logo.png\"></img><div>My logo</div>", true);
            }
        };
        mailSender.send(preparator);
```

And I receive email without image.

When I debug it `logoImage.exists() = true.`

What I do wrong?

**UPD:**`message.getMimeMessage().writeTo(System.out)` print this:

```
    From: myaddress@sh.com
    Reply-To: no-reply@sh.com
    To: kos@inbox.ru
    Message-ID: <2080132943.21504685477046.JavaMail.kn@kn>
    Subject: subject
    MIME-Version: 1.0
    Content-Type: multipart/mixed;
    boundary="----=_Part_1_1016272857.1504685465423"

    ------=_Part_1_1016272857.1504685465423
    Content-Type: multipart/related;
    boundary="----=_Part_2_1648931910.1504685465435"

    ------=_Part_2_1648931910.1504685465435
    Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
    Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
    Content-Disposition: inline
    Content-ID: <logo.png>

<img src="cid:logo.png"></img><div>My logo</div>
    ------=_Part_2_1648931910.1504685465435--

    ------=_Part_1_1016272857.1504685465423--
```

when added this get a message, that my post has mostly code so here is some text don't mind it :)

Comment: isn't it `null` while sending?

Comment: If logoImage isn't `null`, do a `message.getMimeMessage().writeTo(System.out)` and post the result here as part of your question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Look at the [example](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/mail/javamail/MimeMessageHelper.html). I think you should swap the methods `setText` and `addInline`

Comment: @kostepanych Check if the resource not only exists but is not empty by outputting `resource#contentLength`

Comment: logoImage.contentLength()=5560